# How do I use a c library after I configure, make and make install?

Tags: c

I need to use a C library to access and older file format used by a legacy application.  The library I installed was libdbf. (Did ./configure && make && make install).  It was installed under /usr/local/lib:

libdbf.0.0.1.dylib
libdbf.0.dylib
libdbf.a
libdbf.dylib
libdbf.la

I'm loosely familiar with C syntax and have done some very trivial things in C and C++, but don't know how to include the library.

How can I include this library in my project?  Sorry for the noobie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile your project use `-ldbf`

The `-l` means link, and the `dbf` is the name of the library (you don't need to include the `lib` part of the name).

Edit:

I haven't used Qt, but it looks like you can add

```
unix:LIBS += -ldbf
```

To your `.pro` file. Sources [1](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.1/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html), [2](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-03/thread00076-0.html)

By default, gcc will look in `/usr/local/include` for the headers and in `/usr/local/lib` for the library. In case it you need to make it explicit, you can also add:

```
-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Awesome.  So I just use functions provided from the lib and then use that flag when I compile?  Does it make a difference if I'm compiling the project with Qt instead of (for example) gcc?

Comment: Shouldn't do. Compilers will almost certainly look in `/usr/local/include` for the headers and in `/usr/local/lib` for the libraries - but you can use `-I<dir>` and `-L<dir>` to explicitly tell them where to look.

Comment: I thought Qt used gcc internally - does it use a different compiler?

Comment: No, it uses gcc - but I don't type in "gcc" to compile with Qt...so just not sure what to expect.  Thanks for your help = )

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some (untested) Qt specific info.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to compile your project with symbols exported by the library you have to add `-I /usr/local/include`, assuming that the headers were properly installed. For linking you'll need to add `-L /usr/local/lib -ldbf`. You can also pass the path to the library explicitly, so instead of `-L /usr/local/lib -ldbf` add `/usr/local/libdbf.0.dylib`.

See GCC's [linking options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: What if I'm compiling with Qt?

Comment: @CalvinFroedge, before running `qmake` execute `export LDFLAGS="-L /usr/local/lib -ldbf"` and similarly `export CFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include"`. Let me know whether it helped.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge, or use [`QMAKE_LFLAGS`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags) instead of `LDFLAGS`.